# Google Calendar API Exception 'Access is denied.' .NET Core Web App working fine locally, throws an exception when published on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, google-calendar-api

I've written an application which syncs user's Google Calendar Events. Same application works fine when I'm running it locally but when publishing it on azure it throws following exception.

**System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied.**

Application Details:
ASP.NET MVC Core, C#

I've created Client Id for Web Application on Google Application Console.

Some part of stack trace is as below:

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied.
at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener()
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.ReceiveCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.AuthorizeAsync(String userId, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Initializer initializer, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecrets clientSecrets, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver)
```

I'm using below code (which's causing the exception):

```
private CalendarService GetCalendarService(string username)
    {
        UserCredential credential;
      
        //string fileName = "installed_app_secret.json";
        string fileName = "web_app_secret.json";

        string[] scopes = new string[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };

        string clientSecretFile = Path.Combine(_webRootPath, "App_Data", fileName);

        using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                scopes,
                username,
                CancellationToken.None,
                new DbDataStore(this._configuration, _attorneyId)).Result;
        }


        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = _APPLICATION_NAME,
        });
    }
```

Also, I've generated the ClientID for Web Application (Not Installed Application). Json file looks as below:

```
{
"web": {
"client_id": "xxxxxx",
"project_id": "calendar-sync-app-290311",
"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_secret": "yyyyy",
"redirect_uris": [ "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",     "https://<path>/oauth2callback" ]
}
}
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: it's too broad with just this information, but it could potentially be client secrets (as it may pull from environment variables) or url is not being generated\designated properly in that environment... hard to say without diagnostics

Comment: Did you match your redirect URL in the credentials to meet Azure's?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  Sounds like you are using the wrong authorization method for .net core and are using the one for installed applications instead.

Comment: Thanks Dalm. As suggested by you, I've included more information. Hope it should be helpful to figure out the issue.

Comment: Have you gotten any further with this?

Comment: I tried a lot and unfortunately no luck! At last I used the restful APIs and achieved reading/ writing into google calendar.